# How can the dependencies between drop downs be managed?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using JSF2.0. I have three drop downs :

1. masterDropDown.
2. childDropDownA
3. childDropDownB

The business rule that needs to be enforced is :

1. Whenever *masterDropDown* changes , I need to populate *childDropDownA* and *childDropDownB*.
2. The contents of *childDropDownA* and *childDropDownB* are **same except** that when the user selects something from *childDropDownA*, *childDropDownB* should have its old  contents except the one selected by user in *childDropDownA*. The same rule applies when the user selects *childDropDownB* first.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this in JSF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain JSF 2:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="ddlMaster" value="#{bean.ddlMasterSelected}">
        <f:listItems value="#{bean.ddlMasterData}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.fillChildren}" render="ddlChildA ddlChildB" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="ddlChildA" value="#{bean.ddlChildASelected}">
        <f:listItems value="#{bean.ddlChildAData}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.refillChildB}" render="ddlChildB" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="ddlChildB" value="#{bean.ddlChildBSelected}">
        <f:listItems value="#{bean.ddlChildBData}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.refillChildA}" render="ddlChildA" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    private Map<String, String> ddlMasterData;
    private Map<String, String> ddlChildAData;
    private Map<String, String> ddlChildBData;
    private String ddlMasterSelected;
    private String ddlChildASelected;
    private String ddlChildBSelected;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //fill initial values for the drop down lists...
        //this is a raw idea, you must refine it
        DDLService ddlService = new DDLService();
        ddlMasterData = ddlService.getDDLMasterData();
        //empty data for children ddls
        ddlChildAData = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        ddlChildBData = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void refillChildB(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        //filling the children ddls
        DDLService ddlService = new DDLService();
        ddlChildASelected = ddlService.getDDLChildData();
        //same method to fill child data on ddlChildBSelected  because is same data
        ddlChildBSelected = ddlService.getDDLChildData();
    }

    public void fillChildren(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        //when the user selects something from childDropDownA
        //childDropDownB should have its old contents
        //I assume it must be cleared, you can change this behavior though
        ddlChildBData = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    }

    public void refillChildA(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        //The same rule applies when the user selects childDropDownB first
        //I assume it must be cleared, you can change this behavior though
        ddlChildAData = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *render* attribute in `<f:ajax listener="#{bean.refillChildA}" render="ddlChildA" />` work?

Comment: @Inquisitive it will update the contents of `ddlChildA` component, you should provide the id of the components you want to update when the ajax call finishes.

Comment: @Inquisitive you can find more info about `<f:ajax>` [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_ajax.html)

Comment: also why did you choose `LinkedHashMap` over a plain `HashMap` as the datastructure here?

Comment: @Inquisitive because it maintains the order which the elements were added to the map. More info: [`java.util.LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). Note that `HashMap` will just add items in the map, but you don't know for sure its order.

Comment: +1 for the EASIEST way... I made a configurable composite component to handle these situations and it is extraordinarily complex more fitting for a blog post than a StackOverflow answer.